# Highlight words Microsoft Word from checklist, and highlight matching words in checklist too

Tags: vba, ms-word

I using Macro to find word from checklist and highlight in Word document. But If word not found from list then. I also want to highlight matching word in checklist so that I know these word found and these word missing.

One more It also search word inside word that also need to modify. i.e. 
if in checklist I have word `Country` but it find `Count` too, I want if find whole word. But first problem is most important.

```
Sub CompareWordList1()
    Dim sCheckDoc As String
    Dim docRef As Document
    Dim docCurrent As Document
    Dim wrdRef As Object

    sCheckDoc = "D:\List.docx"
    Set docCurrent = Selection.Document
    Set docRef = Documents.Open(sCheckDoc)
    docCurrent.Activate

    With Selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.Font.Bold = True
        .Replacement.Font.ColorIndex = wdDarkRed
        .Replacement.Text = "^&"
        .Forward = True
        .Format = True
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .MatchCase = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
    End With

    For Each wrdRef In docRef.Words
        If Asc(Right(wrdRef, 1)) > 32 Then
            With Selection.Find
                .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                .Text = wrdRef
                .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            End With
        End If
    Next wrdRef

    docRef.Close
    docCurrent.Activate
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is that `.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll` returns `True` if the operation was successful and `False` if nothing was replaced. So we can use this to determine if the word was found or not.

So we can write a function that highlights one word in a document, so that we can re-use that function for different words and different documents:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function HighlightOneWordInDocument(DocToHighlight As Document, ByVal WordToHighlight As String) As Boolean
    If Len(WordToHighlight) = 0 Then Exit Function 'exit if no WordToHighlight is empty otherwise below if fails
    If Asc(Right(WordToHighlight, 1)) > 32 Then
        With DocToHighlight.Content.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Replacement.ClearFormatting
            .Replacement.Font.Bold = True
            .Replacement.Font.ColorIndex = wdDarkRed
            .Replacement.Text = "^&"
            .Forward = True
            .Format = True
            .MatchWholeWord = True
            .MatchCase = True
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Text = WordToHighlight
            HighlightOneWordInDocument = .Execute(Replace:=wdReplaceAll)
        End With
    End If
End Function
```

Then we can use that function to replace a word in a specific document and it returns if `True` if the word was replaced:

```
HighlightOneWordInDocument(docCurrent, wrdRef) 
  'returns true if wrdRef was replaced in docCurrent
```

So we just need to remember the words that were found in an array, so that we can use that array to highlight your word list in the end:

```
Sub CompareWordList1()
    Dim sCheckDoc As String
    Dim docRef As Document
    Dim docCurrent As Document
    Dim wrdRef As Object

    sCheckDoc = "D:\List.docx"
    Set docCurrent = Selection.Document
    Set docRef = Documents.Open(sCheckDoc)
    docCurrent.Activate

    Dim FoundWords() As String
    ReDim FoundWords(0)
    For Each wrdRef In docRef.Words
        If HighlightOneWordInDocument(docCurrent, wrdRef) = True Then
            'if something was replaced remember this word in the FoundWords array
            ReDim Preserve FoundWords(UBound(FoundWords) + 1)
            FoundWords(UBound(FoundWords)) = wrdRef
        End If
    Next wrdRef

    'now we go throug the FoundWords array to highlight the list
    Dim FoundWord As Variant
    For Each FoundWord In FoundWords
        HighlightOneWordInDocument docRef, FoundWord
    Next FoundWord

    docRef.Close 'to save the highligted ist use docRef.Close SaveChanges:=True
    docCurrent.Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: Very Thankful to you for correcting this. I will use this. This helps me lot.

Comment: @Lakhwinder If this solved your issue please consider marking the answer as solution, so everybody sees that this is solved.